# Why this option not working in this Bash script?

Tags: shell-script

I am expanding the following function to include the option `-i | --ignore-case` with error-handling

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "1 argument is needed" && exit 1
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "$1" {} + | vim -
```

Expanded code

```
#!/bin/sh
################################
# Check if parameters options  #
# are given on the commandline #
################################
while (( "$#" )); do
   case "$1" in
    -h | --help)
        echo "help menu"
        exit 0
        ;;
    -i | --ignore-case)
        [ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "1 argumenst i needed" && exit 1
        find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "$1" {} + | vim -
        exit 0
        ;;
     -*)
        echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
      *) # No more options
        break
        ;;
   esac

   shift # not sure if needed
done

# Do this if no cases chosen
[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "1 argument is needed" && exit 1
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l "$1" {} + | vim -
```

Result

1. `haetex "TODO"`. Expected output is the same as output. Passed!
2. `haetex -i "TODO"`. Expected result: search with ignore-case. Result: blank file.

---

Why the option `-i` is not working here?

Comment: When `$1` is `-i`, the string to search for is in `$2`, but you search for `$1`.

Comment: Looks like the question has been revised so my answer is no longer appropriate. Was that a copying error that you've fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a loop at all, since all the cases either exit the script or break out of the loop.

Comment: If I post it as an answer, it won't make sense, since I'll be telling you to do what you're already doing. You shouldn't put the answer into the question.

Comment: How would you do the thing without looping? I think looping is a natural way but not sure.

Comment: Just with the `case` statement. You only need a loop if you want to be able to handle multiple options. In that case, you usually just set variables in the different cases, and then after the loop is done you execute a command that incorporates all the variables.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, yes. I want to handle many options. This thing here is just a simplification of the overall thing with key points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `grep` in the `-i` case to search for `$2`, since `$1` contains the option that you just tested, not the search string.

```
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "$2" {} + | vim -
```

To handle multiple options, it would be better for the `case` statement to just set a variable, e.g.

```
-i | --ignore-case)
    [ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "1 argumenst i needed" && exit 1
    case_option=-i
    ;;
```

Then the `find` command after the loop would look like:

```
find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l $case_option "$1" {} + | vim -
```

In this case it can use `$1` because the `shift` has moved the search string to the beginning of the arguments.

So the whole script looks like:

```
while (( "$#" )); do
   case "$1" in
    -h | --help)
        echo "help menu"
        exit 0
        ;;
    -i | --ignore-case)
        [ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "1 argumenst i needed" && exit 1
        case_option=-i
        ;;
     -*)
        echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
      *) # No more options
        break
        ;;
   esac

   shift # not sure if needed
done

find $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l $case_option "$1" {} + | vim -
```

Comment: What I showed just replaces the `-i)` case from your script, the rest of the loop is the same. I define `case_option` in the code I showed: `case_option=-i`.

Comment: I made a mistake, `shift` isn't needed in the `case`. It just sets the variable, and the shift at the bottom of the loop does the necessary rest.

Comment: I've put the whole script in.